# Download tabulator table with numeric values?

Tags: javascript, xlsx, tabulator

When trying to download data from a Tabulator library table in XLSX format with sheetjs the numeric values in my table are recognized as strings within MS Excel.

I have tried all the parameters in the download function but there is no option for this.

```
table.download("xlsx", "data.xlsx", {sheetName:"MyData"});
```

Expected result is a MS Excel table with numeric values, however I get it with string values, not recognized as numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that you are storing your values in the table as strings rather than numbers.

Have you tried using a [Download Accessor](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/mutators#accessors) to convert the string to a number before it is used in the spreadsheet

for example if you had a age column:

```
//custom accessor
function numberConvert(value, data, type, component){
    return Number(value);
}

//column definition
{title:"Age", field:"ade", accessorDownload:numberConvert}
```